# Making a generic From/Into shortcut for two-steps From

Tags: generics, rust, polymorphism, traits, parametric-polymorphism

`StructA` implements `From<StructB>`, and `StructB` implements `From<S>`.

How can I generically implement a 'shortcut' `Into<StructA> for S` or `From<S> for StructA`?

*If this is a bad idea, please do tell. But kindly explain how to do it anyway for the sake of learning.*

Here's my attempt:

```rust
struct StructA {
    f: StructB
}

struct StructB {
    g: i32
}

impl From<StructB> for StructA {
    fn from(v: StructB) -> Self {
        Self {
            f: v
        }
    }
}

impl From<i32> for StructB {
    fn from(v: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            g: v
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Into<StructA>, S: Into<T>> Into<StructA> for S {
    fn into(self) -> StructA {
        let i: T = self.into();
        i.into()
    }
}
```

The error I get is `the type parameter 'T' is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates`.

I don't understand it. Isn't `T` constrained by `Into<StructA>`?

Comment: This is a bad idea, because it undermines uniqueness of impls. For example you could introduce another type `T0 : Into<StructA>, S: Into<T0>`, now your blanket shortcut implementation is ambiguous. You can achieve something similar with associated types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message basically states that the compiler has no way to infer what type `T` may be – it basically has to figure out whether any type `T` exists such that the given trait bounds `T: Into<StructA>, S: Into<T>` are satisfied, and this is not possible in Rust. One problem with this is, as stated in the comments, that there might be multiple types `T` satisfying the trait bounds, in which case the compiler can't determine which one to use.

In addition, the `Into` trait already has a blanket implementation in the standard library.

```
impl<T, U: From<T>> Into<U> for T;
```

There is no way for the compiler to guarantee that this impl doesn't overlap with your blanket impl, which would also make the implementation ambiguous.

I recommend you simply implement `From<i32> for StructA` explicitly. If you need many such implementations, macros could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand now. I suppose there is no way for the compiler to know/understand that in my case there would only ever be one `T` for each `S` right?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to produce a totally generic solution, because even if you make it past the "unconstrained type parameter" errors you'll then run into "conflicting trait implementation" errors. This is as close as I was able to get, which allows converting `StructB` into `StructA` *or* converting any type which can convert into `StructB` into `StructA`:

```rust
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct StructA {
    f: StructB
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct StructB {
    g: i32
}

impl From<i32> for StructB {
    fn from(v: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            g: v
        }
    }
}

impl<T> From<T> for StructA
where
    T: Into<StructB>
{
    fn from(t: T) -> StructA {
        let structb = t.into();
        StructA {
            f: structb
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a1: StructA = StructB { g: 12 }.into();
    let a2: StructA = 12.into();
    assert_eq!(a1, a2);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69a4f39d6c2bcbb3e334aaed30f6d44c)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is impossible on stable Rust as it would require some form of specialization. Let's consider this code:

```rust
// "StructB -> StructA"
impl From<StructB> for StructA {
    fn from(v: StructB) -> Self {
        Self { f: v }
    }
}

impl From<i32> for StructB {
    fn from(v: i32) -> Self {
        Self { g: v }
    }
}

// "shortcut"
impl<T> From<T> for StructA
where
    StructB: From<T>,
{
    fn from(t: T) -> Self {
        Self::from(StructB::from(t))
    }
}
```

The compiler will complain that the `"StructB -> StructA"` impl conflicts with the `"shortcut"` impl. Which is true since `From<T>` has a [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/convert/mod.rs.html#552-556) for itself.

Now using `Into` will not help at all, since `Into` is reflexive. So even you if you get over the "not constrained" error you'll be back to conflicting implementations.

**However!**
It **is** possible on nightly. With a little trickery using auto traits ([here's a nice article about it](https://pwy.io/en/posts/imitating-specialization-with-oibits/)), we can restrict the "shortcut" implementation to only cover types different than `StructB`.

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a01573ff7993bae66342d890b1a1a2ef)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

> The compiler will complain that the `StructB -> StructB` impl conflicts with the "shortcut" impl.

You mean `StructB -> StructA` right? Because our shortcut is `StructB -> StructA`.

Comment: Yes exactly, fixed it.